# Android Gradle doesn't see dagger hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, dagger-hilt

I have a problem with Gradle.
I'm trying to build a project, but I get an error:

> Plugin [id: 'com.google.dagger.hilt', version: '2.36', apply: false]
> was not found in any of the following sources:
>
> - Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
> - Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.google.dagger.hilt:com.google.dagger.hilt.gradle.plugin:2.36')
>   Searched in the following repositories:
>   Google
>   MavenRepo

Here is my libs.version.toml file:

```
[versions]

# Plugins
android-gradle-plugin = "7.0.0"
spotless-plugin-gradle = "5.12.5"

# Kotlin
kotlin = "1.5.21"
ktlint = "0.41.0"

# AndroidX
androidx-core-ktx = "1.5.0"
androidx-appcompat = "1.3.0"

# UI
material = "1.3.0"

# Hilt DI
hilt = "2.36"

# JVM Unit Tests
junit = "4.13.2"

# Instrumentation Tests
androidx-junit = "1.1.2"
androidx-espresso-core = "3.3.0"

[plugins]

# Plugins
hilt-gradle-plugin = { id = "dagger.hilt.android.plugin", version.ref = "hilt" }
spotless-plugin-gradle = { id = "com.diffplug.spotless", version.ref = "spotless-plugin-gradle" }
kotlin-gradle-plugin = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm", version.ref = "kotlin" }
android-gradle-plugin = { id = "com.android.tools.build.gradle", version.ref = "android-gradle-plugin"}


[libraries]

# Kotlin
kotlin-stdlib = { module = "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib", version.ref = "kotlin" }

# AndroidX
androidx-core-ktx = { module = "androidx.core:core-ktx", version.ref = "androidx-core-ktx" }
androidx-appcompat = { module = "androidx.appcompat:appcompat", version.ref = "androidx-appcompat" }

# UI
material = { module = "com.google.android.material:material", version.ref = "material" }

# Hilt DI
hilt-android = { module = "com.google.dagger:hilt-android", version.ref = "hilt" }
hilt-compiler = { module = "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler", version.ref = "hilt" }

# Hilt DI - JVM / Instrumentation Tests
hilt-testing = { module = "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing", version.ref = "hilt" }

# JVM Unit Tests
junit = { module = "junit:junit", version.ref = "junit" }

# Instrumentation Tests
androidx-junit = { module = "androidx.test.ext:junit", version.ref = "androidx-junit" }
androidx-espresso-core = { module = "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core", version.ref = "androidx-espresso-core" }
```

app\build.gradle:

```
   plugins {
        alias(libs.plugins.hilt.gradle.plugin)
        alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.gradle.plugin)
        alias(libs.plugins.spotless.plugin.gradle)
    }
    
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 31
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.litekite.ime"
            minSdkVersion 24
            targetSdkVersion 31
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        sourceSets {
            main.java.srcDirs += "src/main/kotlin"
            androidTest.assets.srcDirs += files("$projectDir/schemas".toString())
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled true
                shrinkResources true
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        buildFeatures {
            viewBinding = true
            dataBinding = true
        }
        lintOptions {
            baseline file("lint-baseline.xml")
            warningsAsErrors true
            enable "Interoperability"
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        }
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    
        }
    }
    
    kapt {
        correctErrorTypes true
    }
    
    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
        implementation(libs.kotlin.stdlib)
        implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
        implementation(libs.androidx.appcompat)
        implementation(libs.material)
    
        // Hilt
        implementation(libs.hilt.android)
        kapt(libs.hilt.compiler)
    
        // Hilt - Instrumentation test helpers
        androidTestImplementation(libs.hilt.testing)
        kaptAndroidTest(libs.hilt.compiler)
    
        // Hilt - Local unit test helpers
        testImplementation(libs.hilt.testing)
        kaptTest(libs.hilt.compiler)
    
        testImplementation(libs.junit)
        androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
        androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
    }
```

biuld.gradle:

```
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.hilt.gradle.plugin) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.gradle.plugin) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.spotless.plugin.gradle) apply false
   
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

spotless {
    ratchetFrom 'origin/main'
    format 'misc', {
        target '**/*.gradle', '**/*.md', '**/.gitignore'
        trimTrailingWhitespace()
        indentWithSpaces()
        endWithNewline()
    }
    format 'xml', {
        target '**/*.xml'
        trimTrailingWhitespace()
        indentWithSpaces()
        endWithNewline()
    }
    kotlin {
        target '**/src/**/*.kt'
        ktlint(libs.versions.ktlint.get())
        licenseHeaderFile rootProject.file('spotless/copyright.kt')
    }
}
```

I can’t understand what the error is, ChatGPT gives the same answers in a circle.
Please help if anyone knows what is the reason and how to fix it.
I'm using Gradle 8.0

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0-bin.zip

settings.gradle:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

rootProject.name = "IME"
include ':app'

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you include settings.gradle.kts?

Comment: I added settings.gradle

Comment: I think I found the reason for that error, see answer edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing `dagger.hilt.android.plugin` with `com.google.dagger.hilt.android` in the libs.version.toml.

```
hilt-gradle-plugin = { id = "com.google.dagger.hilt.android", version.ref = "hilt" }
```

If this doesn't help, try also removing this from build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

And adding this to setting.gradle:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Edit:

There might be a problem with outdated hilt version, try a newer one like 2.44 or 2.50. There is a caveat though, is might be incompatible with other outdated dependencies.

Comment: Didn't help, same error

Comment: I added another thing worth trying. @VladTkachev

Comment: I tried it, it didn't help either

Comment: What error does it show after all the changes? @VladTkachev

Comment: It gives the same error: Plugin [id: 'com.google.dagger.hilt', version: '2.36', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources. 


I added to the question the full description of the error, which is written by Android Studio